# How do I INSERT INTO SELECT from two different worksheets

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have a sheet `BF_UPLOAD`, that has rows in it.  **I need to add data from two other sheets `Diamond` and `Variations` to BF_UpLoad**.  The two input worksheets need to be joined, neither sheet has all the needed data.

It might be easier to add a column `[Diamond$].name` to the `Variations` sheet before moving the data to the `BF_UpLoad` sheet.

Sheets `Diamond` and `Variations` have a common key `[Diamond$].Code` is the equivalent of `[Varations$].sku`

I think this is the correct JOIN statement.

```
FROM [Diamond$] INNER JOIN [Variations$] ON [DIamond$].code = [Varations$].sku
```

To add records at the bottom of `BF_UpLoad`  I believe I need to use a:

```
INSERT INTO statement
```

The code I am working on is included at the bottom of this posting.  The code works for the sku, `regular_price` and `sale_price` fields.

**I cannot find a way to SELECT data from the two sheets much less get the JOIN to work.**

I have included source data below as well as a sample of the desired output.

**WorkSheets:**

**BF_UpLoad** has the following columns:

```
sku, post_title, regular_price, sale_price
```

**Variations** has the following columns, which are NOT contiguous:

```
sku, regular_price, sale Price
```

**Diamond** has the following columns, which are NOT contiguous:

```
Code, Name
```

On the Diamond sheet `CODE` is equal to the sku column on the other sheets.

**DESIRED OUTPUT IN sheet: BF_UpLoad**

**Sheet: BF_UpLoad: Columns are NOT contiguous**

```
sku         post_title             regular_price  sale_price
ABT00201    BioCare, Fly Trap      11.81          10.69
ABT00204    BioCare,Moth Trap       4.95          9.06  
ABT00415    BioCare,Fruit Fly Trap  6.9           12.63 
AB00017     Acrobird Playland 20"   59.81         56.41
AB00018     Acrobird Playland 24"   79.78         73.24
AB00021     Acrobird Playland 14"   30.84         24.35
```

**INPUT WORKSHEETS**

**Sheet: Diamond: Columns are NOT Contiguous**

```
sku       Name
AB00017   Acrobird Playland 20"
AB00018   Acrobird Playland 24"
AB00021   Acrobird Toddler Playland 14"
```

**Sheet: Variations: Columns are NOT contiguous**

```
sku,      regular_price, sale_price
AB00017   59.81          56.41
AB00018   79.78          73.24
AB00021   30.84          24.35
```

**This is the code I am trying to get working:**

```
Private Sub cmbVariations2BF_UpLoad_Click() 
    Dim objConnection As ADODB.Connection
    Dim objRecordSet As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim strTarget As String
    Dim hdrName As Variant
    Dim wksName As Worksheet
    Dim wksOutput As Worksheet
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim strConnectionString As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Dim strInsert As String

    Dim lngRow As Long

    Dim LastUsedCell As Integer

    Set sh = Sheets("Variations")

    strTarget = "BF_UpLoad"

    pubBF_UpLoadRows = Sheets(strTarget).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row      

    Set objConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    Set objRecordSet = New ADODB.Recordset

    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
                "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"";"

    objConnection.Open strConn

    objConnection.Execute "Insert Into [BF_UpLoad$] (sku, regular_price, Sale_price) SELECT sku, regular_price, Sale_price from [Variations$]"

End Sub
```

Thanks for your input, CraigM

Comment: You are copying values from 1 sheet to another using SQL, why? if you are using VBA you can do it directly using range methods.

Comment: @Nimesh Though Excel has native methods for doing the same thing, there are times that using SQL queries to treat excel tables as a relational database are useful.  Excel ranges can work like relational tables. You can join them by common fields, query them with SQL, and use queries in PivotTables.  Using SQL may also be more familiar to the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, the SQl would be like this:

```
objConnection.Execute "Insert Into [BF_UpLoad$] (sku, post_title, regular_price, Sale_price) SELECT V.sku, D.[Name], V.regular_price, V.Sale_price from [Variations$] V, [Diamond$] D WHERE D.[Code] = V.[sku]"
```

Comment: Thanks Rory, I took me a while to figure it out.  Your solution was the foundation I needed to complete my project.  CraigM